# Transformar String a un operador lógico php eval()

Tags: php, string, operador

Les agradecería que me dieran una forma de pasar un String a un operador matemático pues verán lo que quiero es que al usuario seleccionar dicha operación que va a realizar esta se haga dependiendo el signo que se halla seleccionado

aquí el código para tener mejor idea de lo que busco:

```
<form action="operacion.php" method="post">

numero 1:
<input type="number" name="num1" required=""> <br>
numero 2:
<input type="number" name="num2" required=""> <br>
<select name="opcion">
    <option value="+" >+</option>
    <option value="-" >-</option>
    <option value="*" >*</option>
    <option value="/" >/</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" name="" value="Operar" >



</form>
```

Aqui el codigo PHP

```
<?php 
$x = $_POST['num1'];

$y = $_POST['num2'];

$op = $_POST['opcion'];

if ($op=="+") {
    $Total = $x + $y;
    echo "El total es"." ".$Total;
}

elseif ($op=="-") {
    $Total = $x - $y;
    echo "El total es"." ".$Total;
}

elseif ($op=="*") {
    $Total = $x * $y;
    echo "El total es"." ".$Total;
}

else {
    $Total = $x / $y;
    echo "El total es"." ".$Total;
    return $Total;
}
?>
```

Lo que busco es que al poner simplemente la variable $op ya me realice la operación, explicándome de otra manera al poner por ejemplo "2 $op 3" y suponiendo que $op equivale a un "+", pues que se realice esta operación, sin necesidad de estar validando por if eslseif y else,

por ejemplo :

Total = 2 op 3;
// En total es 5 suponiendo que el usuario escogió en el select el "+"

He leído por algunas partes y dicen que debiera utilizar "eval()" pero no consigo lograrlo, espero me halla explicado bien, les agradecería una respuesta (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero te sirva de ayuda yo lo hice en una función. En esta página encontré como usar la función eval() [eval](https://grokbase.com/t/php/php-general-es/01bwjs9ydx/como-ejecutar-las-operaciones-que-se-encuentran-dentro-de-un-string)

```
<form action="" method="post">


    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        # code...

        $n1 = $_POST['n1'];
        $n2 = $_POST['n2'];
        $op = $_POST['op'];


    function operacion($n1, $n2, $op){

        $resultado =  $n1.$op.$n2;

        eval("\$resultado2=$resultado;");

    return $resultado2;

    }

    echo operacion($n1,$n2,$op);

    }

    ?>
        <select name="op" id="">

            <option value="+">sumar</option>
            <option value="-">restar</option>
            <option value="*">multiplicar</option>
            <option value="/">dividir</option>

        </select>
        <input type="number" name="n1">
        <input type="number" name="n2">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar">
    </form>
```

Comment: @pintowJD Cómo advertencia indicar que el uso de `eval()` en este contexto está totalmente desaconsejado y es altamente peligroso, pues permite a un usuario ejecutar código arbitrario. Imaginemos que un usuario pasa en el primer parámetro lo siguiente por ejenolo: `rmdir(getcwd());//` ¿Qué crees que pasaría?